# Как отфильтровать объекты коллекции IQueryable с помощью свойства объектов из другой коллекции IQueryable используя операции where и contains

Tags: c#, linq, коллекции

Есть две коллекции IQueryable:

1. `IQueryable<> Users`  со свойствами объекта, одно из которых Id
2. `IQueryable<> AuthorizationLogs` cо свойствами объекта, одно из которых userId (что-то вроде внешнего ключа к Id из коллекции Users).

Как с помощью операций where и contains можно отфильтровать коллекцию 
AuthorizationLogs по свойству Id из коллекции Users и вывести count отфильтрованных объектов в коллекции.

По сути реализовал то, что мне нужно через foreach. Смущает большое количество итераций, т.к. каждая из коллекций содержит по 100+ объектов.

```
foreach (var user in users)
{
    foreach (var auth in authUsers)
    {
         if (user.Id == auth.UserId) tCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: По-хорошему, должны использоваться навигационные свойства. Но если их нет (почему?), то обычный linq-запрос с join или where.

Comment: Если в базе 100 пользователей, то сколько бы не было записей в logs то все они будут принадлежать этим 100 пользователям, а потому можно просто считать количество записей. Всё так? Или всё-таки задача не совсем такая простая и нужно искать логи по 10 пользователям из этих 100?

Comment: 1) Навигационных свойств нет. Изначально не подразумевались, в данный момент не могут быть добавлены из-за последующих проблем с миграцией базы данных.                                        2) Условные 100 пользователей бд, которым принадлежат все записи в logs, фильтруются по определенному критерию и уже после этого нужно искать логи по условным 10 пользователям.

Answer (score 0):

для начала, перевести коллекцию в List, например:

```
var list1 = source1.Select(s=>new { s.Id, s.Name }).ToList();
var list2 = source2.Select(s=>new { s.Id, s.Name }).ToList();
```

Второе, сопоставить и выбрать:

```
var T = from a in list1
from b in list2
where a.Id == b.Id
select b;

int count = T?.Count();
```

Comment: Зачем переводить в List? Излишняя операция.

Comment: Думаю, что для подсчета tCount++,  необязательно задействовать все данные в итерации

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
void Main()
{
    IQueryable<User> users = new List<User>()
    {
        new User { Id = 1, A = 123 },
        new User { Id = 2, A = 222 },
        new User { Id = 3, A = 333 },
    }.AsQueryable();

    IQueryable<AuthorizationLog> logs = new List<AuthorizationLog>()
    {
        new AuthorizationLog { UserId = 1, B = 011 },
        new AuthorizationLog { UserId = 2, B = 021 },
        new AuthorizationLog { UserId = 2, B = 022 },
    }.AsQueryable();

    var count = this.GetCount(users, logs);
    //count.Dump();
}

public int GetCount(IQueryable<User> users, IQueryable<AuthorizationLog> logs)
{
    return logs.Count(x => users.Any(y => y.Id == x.UserId));
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class User : TWithId
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TWithId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorizationLog : TWithUserId
{
    public int B { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TWithUserId
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

P.S. С передачей критерия отбора можно уходить куда-то сюда:

```
public int GetCount(IQueryable<User> users, IQueryable<AuthorizationLog> logs, Expression<Func<User, bool>> criteria)
{
    return logs.Count(x => users.Where(u => x.UserId == u.Id).Any(criteria));
}

    var count = this.GetCount(users, logs, x => x.Id != 0 && x.Id < 3);
```